# BigDecimal divide method either returns 0 or ArithmeticException?

Tags: java, double, rounding, division, bigdecimal

When I try dividing BigDecimals using the method:

`divide(divisor, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`

it returns 0

[image]

But if I do it without a rounding mode like this:

`divide(divisor)`

I get an ArithmeticException

[image]

I don't care if the number is not an exact decimal representation. How do I divide BigDecimals without getting 0 or exceptions?

Comment: Why don't you just read the javadoc? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-int-int-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use scale to [divide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,int,int)) `BigDecimal`.

```
  BigDecimal result = amount.divide(fromRate, 6, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```